# PHP Carbon adds 1 minute when ->format('H:m')

Tags: php, php-carbon

I try to show a hour and minute with PHP Carbon like this:

```
$hour = Carbon::parse('2021-01-10 10:00')->format('H:m');
```

and the $hour is 10:01 instead of 10:00.

Why is that?

What do I do wrong?

I use PHP 7.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'm' is the format specifier for "month", which happens to be January (month 1).

For "minute" you need to use 'i' instead:

```
$hour = Carbon::parse('2021-01-10 10:00')->format('H:i');
```

See [the PHP manual page for the `format` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), which Carbon is built on top of.

(If I had a penny for every time I've made this mistake or seen someone else make it, I'd buy you a beer )

Comment: Oh dear. That was such a stupid mistake. (facepalm) Thank you.